# Single quotes in JSRender Syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsrender

I have use JSrender for crating template. I have apostrophe in JSON object value.
So js render showed as syntax error. Any Possible solution for this.

My JSON are as follows.

```
var data={"name":"k'obrain","state":"D.E"}
```

i used js render like this

```
$("#tdCell").html("{{:~value('" + JSON.stringify(data) + "',#data['" + name+ "'],'" + "tempid" + "')}}")
```

When i remove apostrophe from "name" its working fine. Can anyone help to resolve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried escaping it? `var data={"name":"k\'obrain","state":"D.E"}`

Comment: And otherwise you might try replacing the ' by the html special character `&#039;`

Comment: That isn't JSON. It's a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't demonstrate the problem you describe. Please construct a reduced test case showing how you use that data with jsrender to produce the error you get.

Comment: i used bothe escape and replace by html special character, but its not working

Comment: i have edited code snippet, how we are using js render.

Comment: That code is not running the render method of JsRender.  $.templates("{{:name}}").render(data) works fine with your data, apostrophe and all. Is your code pushing content into a template that you then use in JsRender? If so - well the resulting template does have bad syntax.

Comment: @SunilPrabakar For me, the issue is rising while using single quotes not with apostrophe...